# After changing a system disk partition, system won't boot, goes into "Dracut Emergency Shell"; how do I get it to boot?

Tags: boot, uuid, dracut

**Background**

I had a new system that I'd spent a lot of time configuring the software on to perform all manner of services and then discovered the drive was potentially flaky. So I decided to replace the disk, keeping the contents for the new disk.

The system disk also had a problem booting into correct `kernel` that I couldn't seem to fix (I followed all the `grub` directions but it just woudn't boot the right `kernel` by default, only if you manually chose the right one). So, I figured the best way was to simply do a new installation of `Fedora Server` onto the new disk and that would fix the boot problem along the way.

**What Happened**

The new disk was a lot bigger, so I partitioned it a little differently during the installation process. I then removed the drive and put both the new and the old system disk into another server I had nearby. Out of an abundance of caution, I kept the `fstab` from the new system disk, knowing it had the partition `UUIDs`.

There are many ways to move things around and I decided I wanted a clean root partition on the new system disk. I figured `dd` might be able to do this but I'm used to using it where the partitions are the same size and was a little unsure, so instead I just reformatted the root partition ("/") with `gparted`. I then moved the files over using normal OS tools. I then cut and pasted the `UUID` stuff from the new installation and inserted it into the very-non-stock `fstab` from the server I was fixing.

That went fine.

I then attempted to boot the system. It posted, then got to the `grub` boot loader, it automatically selected the right kernel and away it went! ... Until it didn't!

It got to "show Plymouth Boot Screen" or something like that, paused, and then gave a lot of timeout warnings from something calling itself `dracut`. From here, I took a screen shot with my phone. It says:

```
Warning: Could not boot.
Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...
Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/<a uuid> does not exist
Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"
```

followed by a suggestion to use `journalctl` and perhaps to save the `rdsosreport.txt` for bug reporting.

ACK! What to do? I searched high and low for this the `Warning [...] does not exist` and `dracut emergency shell` stuff cited above. Nada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message:

```
Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid> does not exist
```

is a major clue.

It turns out that the root partition's `UUID` is stored in two places in the `grub2` portion of the modern Fedora Server's `/boot` partition.  But in this scenario, there are actually three `UUID` problems.

**The reformatting of the root partition ("/") actually changed the `UUID`.** So, the new `UUID` has to be first discovered and then put into the right locations. There are many ways to find `UUIDs` but one command-line tool to do this is `blkid` - as in this example:

```
# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="64bbac09-1a12-4bea-8873-212ffb56f2a8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="8a09913a-fdb2-42a0-98e3-6b89e16374d2"
```

Note that for each partition, there are two `UUIDs` shown by this tool; you want the first of these. Note also that non-privileged users cannot run `blkid`.

**Here are the three places the root partition's `UUID` needs to be:**

1. In `/etc/fstab` on the line where the root partition mount is described, and;
2. In `/boot/grub2.cfg` on the line setting kernel options. The fast way to find it is to look for the former `UUID` if you still have it. Or look for `"set kernelopts="root=UUID="`, and;
3. In `/boot/grub2/grubenv` on a line that looks similar to the line cited in the `/boot/grub2.cfg` file. Look for: `kernelopts=root=UUID=`

Remember to only change out the one UUID that is new and leave everything else as-was. Maybe make a backup of the file before editing, just in case!

Answer (score 1):

###### Update fstab

One needs to update `/etc/fstab` files with the proper UUID of the partition

###### Update crypttab

If your previous partition was encrypted you need to remove the entry from `/etc/crypttab`

If your new partition is encrypted you need to add the corresponding entry in the `/etc/crypttab`

###### Regenerate initramfs

After updating the `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` file you need to update the initramfs image using dracut.

You could update the dracut image from the dracut emergency shell by running

```bash
# dracut --hostonly --regenerate-all --force
```

###### References

- https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-build-an-initramfs-using-dracut-on-linux

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though I long-ago fixed this, and it didn't involve either initramfs or the dracut command, I'm glad you posted this as I didn't know about these and I'm sure it'll help others at some point!